# Primary reference could not be resolved?? (VB.NET)

Tags: mysql, .net, sql, vb.net, dll

I am trying to connect vb.net 2010 to an SQL database using the MySQL DLL file, however whenever I compile it I am getting the following error:

```
Warning 1   The primary reference "MySql.Data" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".   SQL
```

I have tried it on my desktop as well (also running vb 2010 on windows 8.1) however it won't compile, however on a windows 7 PC it compiles with no issue, despite the fact that the settings appear to be the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. Unload the modeling project by right clicking on it in Solution
   Explorer window and choosing Unload Project.
2. Then right click and click *edit projectname.modelproj.*
3. Then add following code to it.

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
> <ResolveAssemblyReferenceIgnoreTargetFrameworkAttributeVersionMismatch>true</ResolveAssemblyReferenceIgnoreTargetFrameworkAttributeVersionMismatch>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

Comment: "Unload the modeling project" The lower project, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Change in your project properties the `target framework version` to `4.5`
or add a reference with lower version to match your own version (3.5, 4.0)